# dispatch_group_t or dispatch_semaphore_t to wait for multiple async requests to complete

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, semaphore

I need to wait for several requests to complete before I can move on to the next task. dispatch_group_t & dispatch_semaphore_t like quite similar here. So I was wondering which one is better or there is no much difference here.

```
dispatch_group_t serviceGroup = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_group_enter(serviceGroup);
// in completion block
dispatch_group_leave(serviceGroup);

//wait for all requests to complete
dispatch_group_notify(serviceGroup,dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
    // Won't get here until everything has finished
});

/* Or I can use dispatch_semaphore_t */

dispatch_semaphore_t sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
// in completion block
dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem);
// before start request
dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
// Reaching here means all requests has completed
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular situation, the key difference is that the semaphore approach keeps the thread that calls `dispatch_semaphore_wait` alive, but blocked for the entire time, whereas `dispatch_group_notify` returns right away, only executing the block later, leaving the calling thread free to do other things. I would say that `dispatch_group_notify` is the better way to go in this case.

Comment: Yes I know dispatch_group_notify returns right away, only executing the block later while dispatch_semaphore_wait blocked the queue, But since I create a specific queue to do. I guess there is no significant difference. Is that the case ?

Comment: The significant difference is that `dispatch_semaphore_wait` always consumes an OS thread while waiting, `dispatch_group_notify` does not. OS threads are a finite resource.

Comment: Yes it it can. I line up multiple dispatch_group_wait before start the request, dispatch_semaphore_signal in completion  block and that was what my code was trying to show there.

Comment: @Qiulang yes sorry, I wrote that late at night, and while I did point out you could do this, I forgot to change the first sentence to reflect it! Although, while you can technically use semaphores for this, groups are far easier to use, and you can prevent threads from getting blocked through using `dispatch_group_notify`, as ipmcc says. Therefore groups are the way to go.